# Excel function to calculate a sum from a string of numbers

Tags: excel

[image: This is my Dataset]
I have to enter the data in this format: x-y, p-q, ... and I need to sum the differences into a total

Ex: 79.7-79.9, 182.1-200.8 Total 18.9

Right now I just manually calculate the differences and then sum them.
Is there any way to automate this?

Comment: Using VBA, yes. Is that an option?

Comment: I've put "79.7-79.9" in cell D3, and in D4 I've put `="="&D3`, this creates cell D4 with content `=79.7-79.9`, but I don't know how to "evaluate" this.

Comment: Should the answer be -18.9 rather than +18.9?

Comment: I guess I should explain that this is all in one cell except for the total. The numbers are point-intercept data from a meter tape so the total is what length of tape is intercepted by different tree species. I was told to just enter the data the same way it is written and that is how the data set has been done for years

Comment: The `"Before"` and `+` in row 7 are going to be problematic. Ideally there would only be numbers and dashes. Are there any other possible words/characters?

Comment: I'm just entering those in case someone wants to ask the recorder what they meant by writing that, I think it's extraneous info

Answer (score 1):

This works with the basic numbers (no text on the front, or the `+` on the end) and involves helper columns:

In the helper column use this formula to split the segments of numbers across a number of columns (*0-15.2, 20.8-31.2, 39-58.6, 247.5-270* will cover four columns):
`=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A2,", ","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s"))`

Now create a named range - C2 is the first column in the helper column spill range.
`=SUM(EVALUATE(Sheet1!$C2#))`

I named my range EVAL.  `=ABS(EVAL)` in a cell returns 67.7

[image]

Now, this isn't perfect - I tried it with *1-5, 3-2, 8-4* and it came back with 44317, 44230 and 44294 (1st May, 3rd Feb and 8th April) so still needs some work.

**Edit:**
Use `=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A3,", ","*1</s><s>") & "*1</s></t>","//s"))` to avoid the conversion to date problem.
This adds a `*1` to the end of each section so it can't be converted to a date.